# Function to find the minimum number and print it

Tags: c

A very basic (and embarrassing) question which I have not been able to solve yet.

I  created a function`minimum` which, when called, should display the smallest integer that the user has entered into a file. I am also using `atoi`.

The working function is as follows:

```
int minimum(int number) {

static int minNumber = INT_MAX;

if (number < minNumber) {
    minNumber = number;
}
return minNumber;
```

}

Next, I am calling the function later on in the program when I am reading from my file that the user has entered these integers.

**EDIT I am now using the following correct code as suggested below**

```
for (int i = 1; !finished; i++)
{
    if (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) < 1)
        finished = 1;
    else {
        number = atoi(word);
        minNumber = minimum(number);
        printf("\nstring  is \t %s\n", word);
        printf("integer is \t %d\n", number);
    }
}
minimum(number);
```

**Solved** - *My problem is that `number` is always returning my last input as being the smallest.*

Let's say I also want to display the index for this integer, thus determining the position of the smallest number. Is creating another function the way to go? Or can this be done just by altering the present function?

Comment: `static int minNumber = INT_MAX;` - note the `static`. And that call to `minimum` should be *inside* the loop.

Comment: Well you only call minimum once with the last number.

Comment: `minimum` should be, at least, called inside the `for` loop....

Comment: Am I wrong in saying that If I call `minimum` inside the for loop, then, the minimum number will be printed out more than once ?

Comment: @Rizzo It will, but that's because you took a wrong turn when you decided to combine the task of keeping track of the number with the task of printing it. Separate the two. (There's no point in using a function rather than a variable here, by the way)

Comment: @molbdnilo You are suggesting that I remove the `printf` from my function and just include this at the end of my main function?

Comment: This problem is because every time the function is called minNumber is assigned the value INT_MAX. Declare minNumber  as static.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS , just by doing that, my problem is still not solved. It seems like I need to alter something else from my code.

Comment: You have more than one problem in your code and need to fix more than one thing. How many times `minimum` is called during your program execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`minimum(number);` is located **outside** of the loop, so basically you check only the last input.

But moving it inside `for` loop still doesn't solve the problem: every time you call `minimum()` it just compare it to local variable initialized to `INT_MAX` and obviusly returns the number it gets (because it is `< INT_MAX` each time.

So first: as already mentioned in comments by @WhozCraig , create `minNumber` visible to `minimum` function but the same for every call to it: `static int minNumber = INT_MAX;`

`minimum` function now looks like this:

```
int minimum(int number) {

   static int minNumber = INT_MAX;

   if (number < minNumber) {
       minNumber = number;
   }

   return minNumber;                            // return a minimum for later print it out
}
```

Note that I removed call to `printf` because it would print out `minNumber` on every call.

Let's store somewhere minimal value we've found so far:

`int minNumber = 0` before `for` loop

And now inside the loop:

```
...
    else {
        number = atoi(word);
        minNumber = minimum(number);             // now we call it for every input
        printf("\nstring  is \t %s\n", word);
        printf("integer is \t %d\n", number);
    }
...
```

Now simply print it out:

`printf("min number is %d\n", minNumber);`

Btw, there is another by way passing a pointer as suggested by @KeineLust

Comment: Thanks for your contribution on this matter. I will test this method as soon as I get the other method to work.

Comment: I am getting an error in this line of code `minNumber = minimum(number);  ` - value of type "void" cannot be assigned to type "int"

Comment: @Rizzo: Change the return type of your function `void minimum(int number) ` - -> `int minimum(int number) `

Comment: If i want to find the index where the minimum number lies, would it be best to make another separate function ?

Comment: @Rizzo To find an index you can pass a pointer (`int minimum(int number, int *minIndex)` for example) into your function (similar to @KeineLust 's answer) and create `static int index = 0;` inside function to keep track of current index over all numbers. Then _after_ `if` *always* increment `index` by 1 (after because it would give you 0 on first input and we usually count from 0, but place it before `if` and you'll get 1 on first input) and inside `if` do `*minIndex = index;`. To use: in main declare `int i = 0` and now call `minNumber = minimum(number, &i);`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will ask a separate question, enabling other users to give their opinion, and if you want you can answer me again there, for me to accept yet another of your very well structured answers.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `minimum()` the value of `minNumber` is always `INT_MAX`, use a `static`:

```
void minimum(int number) {
    static int minNumber = INT_MAX;

    if (number <= minNumber) {
        minNumber = number;
    }
    printf("min number is %d\n", minNumber);
}
```

or pass `minNumber` to the function:

```
void minimum(int number, int *minNumber) {
    if (number <= *minNumber) {
        *minNumber = number;
    }
    printf("min number is %d\n", *minNumber);
}

int minNumber = INT_MAX;
for (int i = 1; !finished; i++)
{
     ...
     // As pointed out by @YuriyIvaskevych, you need to compare
     // the number in each iteration of the for loop
     number = atoi(word);
     minimum(number, &minNumber);
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight on this matter. I am trying out your second suggestion and I have removed `int minNumber = INT_MAX;` from the function. However I am seeing you included this in the main function? Could you please explain why you did this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because your variable must have an initial value in order to compare inside the function. if you remove the initialization then you compare your number with an uninitialized variable, this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is leading to `'int minNumber': redefinition` error. I have used the `'*'` in your second method as suggested.

Comment: @Rizzo - This is a toy example, but still an example of a powerful idiom. The state for the processing function is kept separate from the function itself. That allows the function to be reused on more than one array for instance. Libraries which need much more extensive state will usually also supply a `void init_state(struct state*);` function.

Comment: Yes, use `intNumber` as an argument in `minimum()`, as suggested in the second example of my answer. (Remove `int minNumber = INT_MAX;`)